# My communities are not displaying. Were my accounts deleted without my notice?

Tags: discussion

So I have noticed that when I want to click on my communities nothing displays. Does this mean that my accounts were deleted without me being notified and why?
This is the image: !

Comment: So if your're downvoting and not how is this helping? I took a screen shot. ?

Comment: They show up just fine for me. Might have just been a small hiccup, I would think. Try loading up your profile page again, and see if you still can't see it. If you can't, check your browser's dev tools for any console errors or network errors, in case some call timed out.

Comment: [I see it ok](http://i.imgur.com/HKMVPhQ.png)

Comment: As a side note, if you're ever worried your other accounts were deleted without notification, you can click on "Network Profile" to the right and at the top of your profile, on the same line as the "Profile" and "Activities" tabs, to go to your profile for the whole network. Your linked accounts should show there just fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.  Maybe the pending chrome update is needed to display properly?  Notice the highlighted Chrome menu in the top right?

Comment: Pretty weird What can be the real issue..  I had refreshed several times.

Comment: Had you tried a hard refresh? (Ctrl + F5) Perhaps it hiccuped and then cached. Is it showing for you now, by chance, or is this still an issue?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ At lest, *maybe* you should :)

Comment: So now i can see them and i did nothing, what was the issue about? was it with stack? because i tried refreshing several times before i decided to ask the question.

Comment: Sounds like it was in fact cached then, if it now works.

Comment: Why only the community segment.. @KevinB

Comment: No idea. caching can be weird and confusing at times, and stackoverflow has a very robust caching system.

Comment: I'd hazard a small there are changes happening right now about login and stack exchanges wide accounts. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-now-live)